# Como colocar efeitos 3D em aplicações do Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, object-pascal

Olá, tenho notado que algumas aplicações em Delphi possuem efeitos gráficos nos formulários de tal forma que assim que o cursor passa sobre uma imagem, por exemplo, ao redor dela surge uma ondulação, já vi isto algumas vezes e queria saber como dar este efeito. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione um componente `TSpeedButton`, vá na propriedade `Glyph` e adicione uma imagem no formato BMP, feito isto vá na propriedade `Flat` e marque-a como `True`.